# Javascript submitting wrong form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

As a workaround for not being able to have nested forms, I've written a system that uses Javascript to update an outside form's hidden input values and then submit the form.  It is working just fine on one page in my site, but for some reason it isn't on another page.  In the browser's JS console, I see the correct ID for the form I want submitted, but the server-side keeps showing a different form's data.

Here are relevant code snippets:

So the button's onclick action calls the JS function updateAndSubmitForm () to submit the actual form I want submitted for this button ("formAddStage") and NOT for the surrounding form "form-update-plan".

```
    <form id="form-update-plan" class="form-horizontal" action="/secure/treatment-components/EditTreatmentPlan" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="requestedAction" value="plan-edit-update">
    ...
      <button role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Add a stage to this treatment plan." 
        onclick='updateAndSubmitForm("formAddStage", ${treatmentPlan.treatmentPlanID }, 0, 0)'> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    ...
    </form>
```

Here is the form "formAddStage" which is at the botton of the page outside of the form that contains the button:

```
<form id="formAddStage" action="/secure/treatment-components/CreateStage" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="requestedAction" value="add-stage-to-treatment-plan">
    <input type="hidden" name="path" value="${path }">  
    <input type="hidden" id="taskIDDynamic" name="taskID" value="" >
    <input type="hidden" id="stageIDDynamic" name="stageID" value="" >
    <input type="hidden" id="treatmentPlanIDDynamic" name="treatmentPlanID" value="${treatmentPlan.treatmentPlanID }">
    <input type="hidden" name="clientUUID" value="${clientUUID }" > 
</form>
```

And here is the JavaScript which gets the form by the ID supplied, gets and sets the values of the hidden fields in that form with the supplied values, then submits.

```
function updateAndSubmitForm(formID, treatmentPlanID, stageID, taskID){
    var form = document.getElementById(formID);

    var inputTaskID = form.elements["taskIDDynamic"];
    inputTaskID.value = taskID;

    var inputStageID = form.elements["stageIDDynamic"];
    inputStageID.value = stageID;

    var inputTreatmentPlanID = form.elements["treatmentPlanIDDynamic"];
    inputTreatmentPlanID.value = treatmentPlanID;

    var requestedAction = form.elements["requestedAction"];
    console.log("Updating and submitting form " + form.id + " - requestedAction: " + requestedAction.value);
    //alert("Updating and submitting form " + formID + " - requestedAction: " + requestedAction.value);


    form.submit();
};
```

So, in summary, clicking the button should call the JS function updateAndSubmitForm() which then gets the form designated in the method's argument "formID" and then take the remaining arguments to update the values of the form and then submit it.

What ends up happening is that my browser console reports the proper information (form id = "formAddStage" and requestedAction = "add-stage-to-treatment-plan") but the server side reports getting information from the form (id="form-update-plan") that is surrounding the button (e.g. request.getParameter("requestedAction") returns "plan-edit-update" instead of "add-stage-to-treatment-plan".

Any ideas about why form.submit() in the JS function does not seem to submit the proper form or why the server is getting a different form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button element within the "form-update-plan" form does not have a type specified, it will therefore be defaulting to a type of submit and submitting the "form-update-plan" form.

Try this:

```
<button type="button"
```

Comment: ah, yes, that did it.  that element was previously a <a>  so I had overlooked changing that attribute.  thanks!